# How to check admob fail to load ad

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, admob

I am developing a MonoGame Android app using Xamarin & VS2012. I want to add Admob banner to my game, so I add the Google Play Services (GingerBread version) component to my app and add the banner as such in code:

```
 _adControl = new AdView(Game1.Activity);
 _adControl.AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner;
 _adControl.AdUnitId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
 var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
 _adControl.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
 Game1.Activity.View.AddView(_adControl);
```

However I cant find anything to hook into when the ad fails to load for whatever reason. There is an _adControl.AdListener.OnAdFailedToLoad() method, but its just a method, not an event, and takes an int whose purpose is unknown. I would appreciate help on how to detect and respond to ad load failure.

Answer (score 1):

Through some guess work I found the solution. You have to create a new class that derives from AdListener and override its OnAdFailedToLoad method to raise any event you define, then subscribe to that event and set your custom adlistener to your ad as such:

```
_customAdListener = new CustomAdListener();
_customAdListener.AdFailedToLoad += CustomAdListenerOnAdFailedToLoad;
_adControl.AdListener = _customAdListener;
```

And it did work when I cutoff the internet connection.